# How to prevent entering the same value second time in sql?

Tags: sql, insert

I have the following problem: I have to create table with projects and employees. Employee can be assigned to few projects, but he cannot be assigned twice to the same projects. How can I prevent doing that?

My tables:

```
use projprac

create table dbo.employees
(
    [idEmployee][int] PRIMARY KEY,
    [name][varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [lastname][varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [pesel][int] UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    [start_project_date][date],
    [end_project_date][date],
    [skills][varchar](80),

    constraint CHK_Date check (end_project_date > start_project_date and end_project_date < GetDate())
)

create table dbo.projects
(
    [idProject][int] NOT NULL,
    [topic][varchar](70) NOT NULL,
    [budget][money] NOT NULL,
    [start_date][date] NOT NULL,
    [end_date][date],
    [realization_in_procent][int],
    [leader][varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [idPEmployee][int],

    primary key (idProject),
    foreign key (idPEmployee) references employees(idPEmployee)
)
```

Comment: if I understand correctly put a unique constraint on table dbo.projekty with columns idProjektu and idPracownika.  Then inserting a record for an employee for a project already assigned will result in a duplicate and violate the unique constraint.

Comment: Showing sample data in English would make things much easier.

Comment: sure, You are right, I will fix it

Comment: @ScottMildenberger excatly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just confirming my reading and summarising before I start

- `Employees` table has one row per employee, and each employee gets an id `idEmployee` (also Primary Key for that table)
- `Projects` has one row per project,with id `idProject` (also Primary Key)
- `Project` currently has a field `idEmployee` which is a foreign key to `Employees`

Now, the question you asked was "Employee can be assigned to few projects but he cannot be assigned twice to the same projects. How can I prevent doing that?"

I think there is an issue with the current question - because at the moment only *one employee can be assigned to each project*. Therefore, an employee cannot be assigned twice to the same project, because only one employee at any time can be assigned to the project. Therefore your structure already prevents this.

I assume, therefore, you're asking one of two questions

- How can we prevent an employee being assigned to multiple projects? or
- How do I change the structure so that multiple employees can be assigned to a given project, but stop the same employee being assigned twice to that project?

I'll answer each of these in turn

**How to prevent an employee being assigned to multiple projects**

The initial temptation is to do a unique constraint in the Project table, on idEmployee. However, there is an issue with NULLs. Unique constraints don't allow multiple NULLs - meaning projects will always need to have an idEmployee applied.

Instead, use a filtered unique index e.g.,

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Project_Employee 
ON dbo.Project
    (idEmployee) 
WHERE (idEmployee IS NOT NULL);
```

This acts similarly to a constraint, but only on records where idEmployee is not NULL.

Edit: Another approach to do this is simply to put idProject in the `Employees` table, so each employee can only have one Project (and removing idEmployee from the `Project` table). However, this means multiple employees can be assigned to the same Project.

**Allowing multiple employees on the same project**

To do this, you need a many-to-many table between `Project` and `Employee`. If you add a primary key covering the two ID fields, then it automatically won't allow duplicates.

```
CREATE TABLE project_employee (
    idProject int,
    idEmployee int,
    PRIMARY KEY (idProject, idEmployee)
    )
```

Then remove the idEmployee field from the `Project` table - and instead put all the relevant employees in this new many-to-many table.

Comment: Sigh - will edit to be English fields now!

Comment: I really appreciate the comment, thank You so much for Your help!